# Is there a bigger class of groups such that $h(G)\leq cd(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, amenability

By Theorem 5 of "The Algebraic Characterization of Geometric 4-Manifolds" by Hillman, if $G$ is an elementary amenable group of finite cohomological dimension, then $h(G)\leq cd(G)$.

My question is that is there a bigger class of finitely presented groups of finite cohomological dimension such that $h(G)\leq cd(G)$?

By Corollary 2.5 of "Cohomology of rings" by Brown, if $cd(G)<\infty$, then $G$ is torsion free.

Comment: How is $h(G)$ defined for a general group $G$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Hirsch length is defined for all groups but if it is finite it is amenable.

Comment: But I asked you how you defined it.

Comment: @DerekHolt The Hirsch length of a group $G$, $h(G)$, is equal to $n\geq 0$ if $G$ has a series $1=H_0 \lhd \cdots \lhd H_r =G$ in which the factors are either locally finite or infinite cyclic, and exactly $n$ factors are infinite cyclic. In all other cases, $h(G)=\infty$.

Comment: OK, so it $h(G)$ is finite, then $G$ is elementary amenable. So how could there possibly be a bigger class of groups of finite cohomological dimension with $h(G) \le {\rm cd}(G)$? The answer to your question is no.

Comment: @DerekHolt I got it. Thanks very much. Could you please give a reference for your statement:  if $h(G)$ is finite, then $G$ is elementary amenable?

Comment: I don't know a reference but it follows directly from the definition of elementary amenable: closure under direct union implies locally finite groups are elementary amenable, then use closure under extension.